# making solder stick to the tip of a brushless motor

Tags: soldering, brushless-dc-motor, glue

I have a brushless motor like [this](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/oj0AAOSwubRXGOgf/s-l1600.jpg) and want to attach some sort of steel bar like a needle to it. I am currently using superglue, however even after using a lot it still makes the bar come of rather easily and takes a lot of effort to properly glue. I tried using solder instead, but the tip of the motor seems to be coated in something or consist of some sort of metal that doesn't allow for regular solder to stick to it. Someone recommended coating it in flux, but this seems to not have any effect. Is there a way to attach it without having to make use of special tools that e.g. press the metal around the tip?

Comment: I would do just what you said a press a tube around it and the needle. From your attempts though it sounds like this isn't load bearing. Soldering a motor that small would also probably get the entire motor hot enough to damage the magnets.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You should inline the image so we don't all have to follow a link to understand your question. In any case there is no electrical engineering content to your question other than it happens to involve an electric motor and you're trying to use solder which is used in electronics. It's probably a better fit for engineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DKNguyen do you mean some sort of heat shrinking tube? And if the needle is set perpendicular to the motor what would that look like?

Comment: I was thinking more of crimping a metal tube onto the shaft and needle. Also, you never specified the orientation in your original question so it never even occured to me you might want it perpendicular. I assumed it was parallel to the shaft.

Comment: You may need a different type of flux. I believe even steel can be soldered to with the correct flux. I think hydrocloric acid can be used for this; although it's extremely caustic obviously.

Comment: Maybe you could share a photo of what one of the glued ones looks like?

Comment: My guess is the shaft is stainless steel, you're not going to get standard solder to stick to it. You would need something like a silver solder and effectively braise it... You're much better off with mechanical attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start on a toolbox!   First purchase: a crimping tool and a bunch of solderless terminals (ring-lugs, butt-splices, quick-discon, etc.)   These kits are sold in the electrical aisle of hardware stores.  Cheap $10 from Harbor-Freight Tool #67584, "solderless terminals" kit with crimp tool.

Now just securely crimp a copper terminal onto the motor shaft.  Cut away the part you don't want.  Remove the red plastic cover.  Now just solder anything onto the copper.  (Perhaps add a drop of superglue afterwards, to make it more permanent.  Don't burn the glue by soldering thought.)

Next, buy a drill and a set of drill bits.   Now you can drill a hole in a small piece of brass (or even in a piece of very thick copper wire,) where the hole fits the motor shaft.